# getElementByClassName returning 'undefined', but it works for Id?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to change the contents of an `Id` with a `class`, and I don't know why this isn't working...

```
<h1 id="header">header</h1>
<h4 id="sub">sub header</h4>

<span class="content">Please work!</span>
```

This is returning 'undefined', and my text editor doesn't seem to recognise `getElementsByClassName` - it works fine with `getElementById`

```
 var test = document.getElementsByClassName("content").innerHTML;

 document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = test;
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/wadc/ot9e6hwL/)**

Comment: When using `document.getElementsByClassName("content")` it returns an object collection (much like an array)! You must do something like this `document.getElementsByClassName("content")[index]`

Comment: @www139—it returns an [*HTMLCollection*](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110705/common-dom-interfaces.html#htmlcollection-0), not an Array.

Comment: @RobG Thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: If you're only looking for the first element with the class, consider using `document.querySelector('.content')`, which will behave much like *getElementById*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var test = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].innerHTML;
document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = test;
```

```html
<h1 id="header">header</h1>
<h4 id="sub">sub header</h4>


<span class="content">It's working!</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The key to your Problem is the little "s" hidden in the expression: "getElement**s**ByClassName". `document.getElementsByClassName` will return an array, in order to get the first element use `document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0]` or use a for loop to loop through all elements

```js
var test = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].innerHTML;

document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = test;

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("content")
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
  // elements[i]
}
```

```html
<h1 id="header">header</h1>
<h4 id="sub">sub header</h4>

<span class="content">Please work!</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Access it like this :-

```
document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0];
```

`getElementsByClassName()` method gets many DOM elements unlike `getElementById()` which gets only one.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problem. Let me know if there is anything I can do :)

`document.getElementById` returns only one element. `document.getElementsByClassName` and `document.getElementsByTagName` can return multiple elements because there can be multiple `a` elements on a page and multiple class names used on a page but there can only be one id per page. That being said, you must tell JavaScript which element you are wanting since there can be multiple elements with the class name of `content`. To do this, you use `document.getElementsByClassName('content')[index]`. Many people like to use loops here to quickly loop through all the elements with a specific class or tag name.

Hope you learned something, I learn something here every day too :)

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var test = document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0].innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = test;
});
```

```html
<h1 id="header">Default header HTML</h1>
<h4 id="sub">sub header</h4>

<span class="content">Content HTML</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements (whereas `getElementById` returns a single element -- notice plural vs. singular). Since a javascript array does not have the `innerHTML` attribute, you are getting the undefined. You must retrieve an element out of the array first. e.g.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
var firstElement = elements[0];
var x = firstElement.innerHTML // and so on...
```